# Computing the speed of a traveling front explicitly for an example

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am considering the reaction-diffusion equation
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
u_{t}=u_{xx}+f(u)
\end{equation}
with non-linearity
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
f(u)=-u+H(u-\alpha),\quad0<\alpha<1,
\end{equation}
where $H(u)$ is the Heaviside function.

The values $u=0$ and $u=1$ are stable spatially homogeneous equilibria.

> > Find speed $c$ such that $v(\xi), \xi:=x+ct$, is a traveling front with $\lim_{\xi\to-\infty}v(\xi)=0$ and $\lim_{\xi\to\infty}v(\xi)=1$.

Substituting $v(\xi)$ into (1) gives
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
v_{\xi\xi}-cv_{\xi}+f(v)=0
\end{equation}
or, equivalently, the system
\begin{align}\tag{3'}
&v_{\xi}=w\\
&w_{\xi}=cw-f(v).
\end{align}

If a such a front exists,

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}w^2\, d\xi=\int_{0}^1f(v)\, du.
\end{equation}
This follows by multiplying (3) by $v_{\xi}$ and integrating from $\xi=-\infty$ to $\xi=\infty$.

> > For most functions $f(u)$, it is necessary to calculate $c$ numerically. However, in the special case of (2), it is said, the speed $c$ can be calculated directly to be
> >     \begin{equation}\tag{5}
> > c=\frac{1-2\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha-\alpha^2}}.
> > \end{equation}

I tried to verify (5):

I think what I can compute is
$$
\int_{0}^1f(v)\, dv=-\underbrace{\int_{0}^1 v\, dv}_{=\frac{1}{2}}+\underbrace{\int_0^1H(v-\alpha)\, dv}_{=\int_{-\alpha}^{1-\alpha}H(y)\, dy}=-\frac{1}{2}+[H(y)y]_{-\alpha}^{1-\alpha}=-\frac{1}{2}+1-\alpha=\frac{1-2\alpha}{2}
$$

So what I got up to now is only
$$
c=\frac{1-2\alpha}{2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}w^2\, d\xi}.
$$

But I do not know how to compute
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}w^2\, d\xi=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(v_{\xi})^2\, d\xi.
$$
Maybe it helps to use (3'), i.e. that
$$
w=\frac{w_{\xi}+f(v)}{c},
$$
giving
\begin{align}
w^2&=\frac{(w_{\xi}+f(v))^2}{c^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{c^2}(f(v)^2+2w_{\xi}f(v)+(w_{\xi})^2)\\
&=\frac{1}{c^2}\left[v^2+(w_{\xi})^2-2w_{\xi}v+H(v-\alpha)\cdot (-2v+H(v-\alpha)+2w_{\xi})\right]
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can find a traveling wave solution explicity. Look for a solution $v$ that satisfies $v(0) = \alpha$ and is continuously differentiable there. Then for $\xi < 0$ the equation becomes $v'' - cv' - v = 0$ and for $\xi > 0$ the equation becomes $v'' - cv' - v + 1 = 0$.

These are just ordinary differential equations with constant coefficients, so we can write down the solutions.
For general $c$, the separate solutions with the correct limiting behavior at $ \pm \infty$ are $v_1(\xi) = \alpha e^{z_1 \xi}$ for $\xi < 0$ and $v_2(\xi) = 1 + (\alpha - 1) e^{z_2 \xi}$ for $\xi > 0$, where $z_1 = \frac{c}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4} +1}$ and $z_1 = \frac{c}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4} +1}$.

Then $v_1(0) = v_2(0)$ by construction. You also want $v_1'(0) = v_2'(0)$, which leads to the additional condition
$\alpha z_1 = (\alpha - 1)z_2
$.

Now solve this equation for $c$ and the formula for the wave speed follows.

Comment: You can shift a traveling wave solution connecting 0 and 1 so that $v(0)$ takes any value in the interval $(0,1)$. In addition, your system of equations requires that $w_\xi$ may have a jump but must otherwise be finite, that is $v_\xi= w$ must be continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a nice answer. I am still interested how it is possible to compute $c$ by the formula (5) directly (i.e. without your ansatz etc.).

Comment: Maybe this is not possible and I just missunderstood the exercise: I thought  the task is to compute $c$ by using formula (5). But maybe it was meant in a way that goes in the direction of your answer...